# Swicth case en python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

quisiera saber como de puede implementar swicth en python.
Por ejemplo, tengo este ejemplo en java:

```
do {
        int op = menu();
        switch(op) {
        case 0: 
            break;
        case 1:
            //inicio la partida, generos los dos cartones y genero el bombo
            aux = iniciarPartida();
            carton1 = (int[][]) aux[0];
            carton2 = (int[][]) aux[1];
            bombo =(int[]) aux[2];
            excepcion= true;
            break;
        case 2:
            //Saco una bola del bombo
            if(excepcion==true){
                sacarBola(bombo, carton1, carton2);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Primero debes iniciar partida");
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            //Imprimo los cartones de cada jugador
            if(excepcion==true){
                System.out.println("Carton de " + nombres[0] + ":");
                imprimirCarton(carton1);
                System.out.println("Carton de " + nombres[1] + ":");
                imprimirCarton(carton2);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Primero debes iniciar partida.\nIntroduce 1.");
            }
            break;

        default://Si no itroduces una opción entre el 1 al 3 no se ejecuta.
            System.out.println("Opcion no válida. Rango admitido: 1-3");
        }
    }while(seguir);
```

Quisiera saber como puedo implementarlo en python, y quisiera saber si en los switch case se puede tener varias cosas dentro de cada caso llamando a varios def.

Answer (score 2):

Como ya debes saber, en python no existen los `do` - `while` ni los `switch` - `case`
Sin embargo esas estructuras pueden ser perfectamente emuladas por el lenguaje.
En el caso del `do` - `while`, simplemente hay que dar una condición inicial verdadera y luego evaluar dentro del ciclo si se sigue cumpliendo la condición inicial o no.
Ejemplo:

```
iter = True
while iter == True: # Funciona igual si solo pones while iter:
    [ Rutinas ]
    .
    .
    .
    if [condicion]:
        iter = False
```

Otra forma

```
while True: 
    [ Rutinas ]
    .
    .
    .
    if [condicion]:
        break
```

En el caso del `switch`, es similar a estructuras `if` o `if-elif-else`.

Si la condición no es estricta, o sea, que los `case` no tienen `break`, entonces la estructura en python es:

```
default_op = True
if condicion1:
    default_op = False
    [ rutina1 ]
if condicion2:
    default_op = False
    [ rutina2 ]
if condicion3:
    default_op = False
    [ rutina3 ]
.
.
.
if default_op:
    [ rutina default ]
```

En el caso de `switch` en que los `case` tengan `break` entonces servirá esta otra estructura

```
if condicion1:
    [ rutina1 ]
elif condicion2:
    [ rutina2 ]
elif condicion3:
    [ rutina3 ]
.
.
.
else: # default
    [ rutina default ]
```

Obviamente si en tu `switch` tienes una mezcla de `case` con `break` y `case` sin `break`, en python tendrás que tratar ambos casos por separado como ya lo mostré.

Answer (score 0):

On Python 3.10 is already posible to do that what you want, with the new **match** sentence:

```py
match subject:
    case <pattern_1>:
        <action_1>
    case <pattern_2>:
        <action_2>
    case <pattern_3>:
        <action_3>
    case _:
        <action_wildcard>
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a SO **en español**! Por favor, traduce tu respuesta usando el idioma oficial del sitio. Gracias. De paso léete [answer] y haz el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y cómo elaborar buenas respuestas.